# How to include .ttc font file format in html using link tag

Tags: javascript, css, html, sass

I try to use link tag,but its not working.

Basically , I want to add dynamic path for the URL in my App.scss file

```
@font-face {
  font-family: XYZ;
  src: url("../public/fonts/XYZ.ttc");
}
```

So there are two things i want to figure out :

1) is there a way to use .ttc file format in link as i can use in scss file.

2) can i call javascript function in scss file (to know the exact path).

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: When i am using the @font-face in scss file, it is pciking all the font options and attributes ,but instead of defining in scss file , when i include the font in index.html file using link tag,it has not picked the font attributes.

Comment: I have used this  <link rel="stylesheet"  href="XYZ.ttc">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK TrueType Collection (TTC) which is an extension of TrueType format are not supported by design and there is not reference int the specification, you could try to convert a subset of your font to TTF and link that one instead.